# союзы "если" и "если... то" - какая разница?

Tags: союзы

> В таких случаях, **если** даже один член коллегии выступает против смертной казни, **то** этого достаточно для пожизненного заключения, так как для смертной казни требуется единогласное решение всех присяжных.

Обязательно ли здесь "то"?

Какая разница между союзами "если" и "если.. то"?

Например:

> 1.**Если** пройдет дождь, асфальт будет мокрый.
>   2.**Если** я читал, **то** он писал.

В первом случае "если" - подчинительный союз. Во втором предложении "если... то" - сопоставительный, и, если отбросить "то", будет другой смысл предложения.

А если добавить "то" в первом предложении, (то?) вроде бы смысл не поменяется.

Answer (score 4):

В придаточных условия союзы ЕСЛИ и ЕСЛИ...ТО близки по значению, ТО - факультативный коррелят, дополнительный структурный элемент со  значением следствия. Он переводит условные отношения в условно-следственные отношения.

Двойной союз ЕСЛИ...ТО в сопоставительных предложениях является специализированным, причем он имеет двойную специализацию: может выражать соответствие или несоответствие в зависимости от контекста. В этом случае элемент ТО является обязательным.